# Android splash screen with a different image each time the app starts

Tags: android

I am making a splash screen which shows for 4 to 5 secs, then the log in screen appears.
How to store 4 to 5 images in splash screen?

I want to change the splash screen image every time when user starts the application.
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the onCreate() of your activity, you can do this to choose a random background from your 5 backgrounds:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize your activity and it's componments
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ...

    // Randomise a background
    int[] yourListOfImages= {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image5};

    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int posOfImage = random.nextInt(yourListOfImages.length - 1);

    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
}
```

You can use an infinite count of images

Comment: in this i cant set the layout (setContentView(R.layout.Splash))..?

Comment: got this error :  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity, android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: don't forget setContentView(...)

Comment: its working but splash screen change when app start after 1 min.i want ot change splash screen when app start in a min more than two time

Answer (score 2):

you could use an array of int with the id of the drawables you want to use. Store the index of the last drawable you showed in the `SharedPreference` and retrieve it when the application starts, increment it and store it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have some images in your resources, and then you can randomly set the image of the splash screen.

Here is an example to randomly set ImageView image resource:

```
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
Random rand = new Random();
int rndInt = rand.nextInt(n) + 1; // n = the number of images, that start at idx 1
String imgName = "img" + rndInt;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());  
imgView.setImageResource(id);
```